# Authenticating JWT token with .jks key in Kong API Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices, kong

I am using *Spring Boot* where I create a *JWT token* and sign with *.jks* private key.

Now I want to authenticate the token in *Kong API Gateway* with this *.jks* key but I can't find a solution to import this key in the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jwt plugin you can specify the `rsa_public_key`

For example:

```sh
$ curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/consumers/{consumer}/jwt \
    -F "algorithm=RS256" \
    -F "rsa_public_key=@./pubkey.pem" \
    -F "key=XXXXX" # the `iss` field
```

If it is in your own plugin you can use the kong `jwt_parser` and the `verify_signature` function

```lua
local jwt_decoder = require "kong.plugins.jwt.jwt_parser"
jwt:verify_signature(your_public_rsakey)
```